# Computing for Sample Standard Deviation

Tags: java, android

In the code below I wanted to get sample standard deviation but I got (population standard deviation) instead of (sample standard 
     deviation), What am I doing wrong?

```
public void compute(View view) {


    no1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
    no2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
    no3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());

    m = (no1 + no2 + no3)/3;
        mm1= (no1-m);
        mm1 = mm1*mm1;

        mm2= (no2-m);
        mm2 = mm2*mm2;

        mm3= (no3-m);
        mm3 = mm3*mm3;

        std = (mm1+mm2+mm3)/3;

       tv1.setText(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(std)));


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate an estimate of the population using a random sample of that population (the "sample standard deviation") then the calculation is almost the same, but the dividend needs to be decreased by one.

In other words, your sample size is three so you need to divide by two in order to adjust for the fact you're working from a sample and not the entire population. So your final line of calculation needs to look like this:

```
std = (mm1 + mm2 + mm3) / 2;
```

You can find numerous pages online which give a detailed explanation about the difference between population and sample standard deviation, such as [this article on macroption.com](http://www.macroption.com/population-sample-variance-standard-deviation/).